# How can I embed an external image within a tikzpicture environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to embed an image within a `tikzpicture` environment. I tried the following,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \pgftext{\includegraphics[width=150pt]{pic1.png}} at (0pt,0pt);
  \pgftext{\includegraphics[width=150pt]{pic2.png}} at (100pt,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but both pictures are placed at upper-left corner of image, at the same position. I tried including them inside nodes as well, to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `\node (myfirstpic) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{pic1.png}};`

Comment: @Jubobs - that worked! Thanks. Seems that in my earlier attempt I tried to nest \includegraphics inside \pgftext.

Comment: `\pgftext` is not a TikZ command. The `\node` thing from @Jubobs should work. `\pgftext[at={\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}]{…}` and `\pgftext[x=100pt, y=0pt]{…}` are possible `\pgftext` solutions. (The `at …` stuff you wrote is just ignored by TikZ as usual.)

Comment: Closely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: Related [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95273/15717](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95273/15717)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/tikz-using-external-images-as-building-blocks

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The prefered way to embed external pictures in a `tikzpicture` environment is to insert an `\includegraphics{...}` inside a `\node`. See the code below for an example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{bertrand_russell.jpg}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (5,-6)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{alfred_north_whitehead.jpg}};
\draw[<->,thick] (russell.south east) -- (whitehead.north west)
    node[midway,fill=white] {Principia Mathematica};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Links to the original pictures:

- http://www.brainpickings.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/bertrandrussell2.jpg
- http://www.fotosimagenes.org/imagenes/alfred-north-whitehead-8.jpg

Comment: What's the use of the `inner sep=0pt` option?

Comment: @nemarona Try to use `inner sep=10pt` (for example) and recompile. `inner sep=0pt` tells TikZ to make the node's bounding box as tight as possible around the image.

Comment: How do the image widths compare to the tikz coordinates?

Comment: There is some form to use mid north west o mid south east?. Thanks

Comment: Re. @ThomasAhle it's the normal one, see [context - Setting unit length in TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15994/setting-unit-length-in-tikz) (default is 1 unit = 1cm)

Comment: Does it need to be a jpg?