# How can I insert a picture into a TikZ diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, bitmap

I want to insert a picture into a TikZ graphic, is it possible?

An example:

[image: diagram]

Comment: `\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{your picture}};` Change postion `(0,0)` and `width`.  You can also do it with `pgfplots`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115087/how-do-i-embed-an-external-image-within-tikzpicture

Answer (score 3):

it works better with: `\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{your picture}};`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A "fuller" MWE would probably make your answer more helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `pgfplots`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,axis on top,xlabel = Displacement
                   (\si{\milli\meter}), ylabel = Load (\si{\kilo\newton})]
       \addplot graphics
       [xmin=0,xmax=8,ymin=0,ymax=90]
       {example-image-a};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May be it is better to plot it using `pgfplots`