# TikZ get current unit length of x-coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am searching for a macro which prints the current x-unit-length.
For instance the following document:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=3cm]
    \node at (0,0) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want a macro which can return the '2cm' of 'x' or '3cm' of y.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\getxlengthincm#1{
  \path let \p{x}=(1,0), \n{xlencm}={scalar(veclen(\x{x},\y{x})/1cm)}
  in \pgfextra{\xdef#1{\n{xlencm}}};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=3cm]
  \getxlengthincm{\myxlength}
  \node[align=center] at (0,0) {x length:\myxlength cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a variant with explicit `pt` unit:

```
\def\getxlength#1{
  \path let \p{x}=(1,0), \n{xlen}={veclen(\x{x},\y{x})}
  in \pgfextra{\xdef#1{\n{xlen}}};
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `\path let \p{x}=(1,0), \n{xlencm}={scalar(\x{x}/1cm)}` without `veclen` ?

Comment: @Kpym the value of `x` (and `y`) can be a length **or** a coordinate.

Comment: I also want the unit, so, cm to be retrieved. Here you added it as text.

Comment: @PaulGaborit you use it here with `\p{x}=(1,0)` so `veclen(\x{x},\y{x})` and `\x{x}` are the same, no ?

Comment: @Kpym Try with `x={(1cm,1cm)}` for example...

Comment: @Arne The natural unit is `pt`. I provided a variant with an explicit `pt`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit ok, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `printlen` package and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15996/36296

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{printlen}

\newlength{\pgfx}
\newlength{\pgfy}

\uselengthunit{cm}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=3cm]
    \node at (0,0) {};
    \pgfpointxy{1}{1};
    \makeatletter
    \setlength{\pgfx}{\pgf@x}
    \setlength{\pgfy}{\pgf@y}
    \makeatother
    \node {\printlength{\pgfx}~\printlength{\pgfy}}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there is no simple, native macro which can do this. Feels a bit weird to me ;)

Comment: @Arne I did not say that, just that you could do it like this

Comment: If I replace `y=3cm` by `y={(-2cm,1cm)}`, I got a wrong result!

Comment: What does `y={(-2cm,1cm)}` mean? I thought `y` is a coordinate...

Comment: @Arne As far as I understand this would result in a tilted coordinate system?

Comment: @Arne `x` defines the x-vector. You can use `x=1cm` (equivalent to `x={(1cm,0)}`) or a true vector as `x={(1cm,5mm)}` (see pp.357-358, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,luatex85,siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\NodeDist}[3][\MyDist]{%
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
                 {\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}
    % no need to use a new dimen
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    % to convert from pt to cm   
    \pgfmathparse{veclen(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya)/28.45274}
    \global\let#1\pgfmathresult % we need a global macro    
}

\newcommand{\TZUnits}{
    \coordinate (@0) at (0,0) ;
    \coordinate (@X) at (1,0) ;
    \coordinate (@Y) at (0,1) ;
    \NodeDist[\Xunit]{@0}{@X}\edef\Xunit{\SI{\Xunit}{\cm}}
    \NodeDist[\Yunit]{@0}{@Y}\edef\Yunit{\SI{\Yunit}{\cm}}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=3cm]
    \TZUnits
    \node {\Xunit~\Yunit}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here, also the unit (cm) is missing.

Comment: Vos désirs font désordre...