# On adding a rounded rect node on top of a JPEG at a scaled coordinate position with the scaled inner xsep and ysep

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, coordinates, tikz-node

Let us assume that we have a JPEG file of mushrooms given in the following link:
[WIKI MUSHROOMS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Mycena_interrupta.jpg)

To make it easier to find the desired points in the JPEG, Let us draw a labeled grid on top of the image following the answer of Jake at the link below:
[Jake Label Grid on Top of JPEG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)
Following Jake answer we define a coordinate system having its (0,0) at the southwest and (1,1) at the northeast of the JPEG.
Let us assume that we want to add a rounded rect node at the scaled (0.5, 0.5) of the JPEG with the inner xsep= 0.2 unit and inner ysep= 0.2 scaled unit.
Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.misc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newcommand{\midfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{b}{n}\fontsize{15}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth] 
{mushrooms.jpg}};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
\node at ( {.5+0},.5) [ red, line width=2 pt, shape=rounded rectangle,draw, inner xsep=30, 
inner ysep=20] (rect){};
\node at ( {.5-.2},{.5+.2}) (text){\textcolor{red}{\midfont{Center is Here}}};
\draw [line width=3 pt, red][->] (rect) -- (text);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have two questions as below:

1. What is the meaning of [x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}] after scope declaration?
2. I wanted to use 0.2 scaled unit for inner x sep and y sep to span my rounded rect node 0.2 unit along x and .2 unit along y. but in order to do that I had to use inner xsep=30,
   inner ysep=20. I did it by trial and error. Is there any more accurate way to get the correct values of inner xsep and ysep to obtain exactly 0.2 scaled unit for both x and y direction for the rect node?
   [image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x={(image.south east)}, y={(image.north west)}` in the optional argument of `scope` defines the `/tikz/x` and `/tikz/y` unit vectors within the given `scope` so that, in the low-level PGF drawing system:

- the *x* coordinate of `/tikz/x` is the width of the image in points and its *y* coordinate is `0pt`;
- the *x* coordinate of `/tikz/y` is `0pt` and its *y* coordinate is the height of the image in points.

This works because the preceding code:

```
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{mushrooms.jpg}};
```

defined `image` as a tight rectangular node around the image, whose `south west` corner has been placed at the origin `(0,0)`.

Regarding what you want to achieve, most Ti*k*Z options that expect a length interpret a unitless input as a length in *points*, which is why you had to use trial and error and give “large” values to `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`. I'd rather use the `minimum width` and `minimum height` options to determine the desired width and height for the `rect` node. One still needs to either give them with explicit units, or provide the lengths in *points*. I'll use simple `\getxlength` and `\getylength` macros to allow easy storing of the current lengths of the `/tikz/x` and `/tikz/y` vectors, expressed in points (other techniques can be found in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424785/73317)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.misc}

\newcommand{\midfont}{\fontsize{15}{18}\usefont{T1}{lmss}{m}{n}}

\makeatletter
% These assume that the /tikz/x vector is “horizontal” and /tikz/y “vertical”.
\newcommand*{\getxlength}[1]{\edef#1{\the\pgf@xx}}
\newcommand*{\getylength}[1]{\edef#1{\the\pgf@yy}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{mushrooms.jpg}};

\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)}, y={(image.north west)}]
  \draw[help lines, xstep=.1, ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10, 0) {0.\x}; }
  \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0, \y/10) {0.\y}; }

  % Get the unit vector lengths in points
  \getxlength{\xLen} \getylength{\yLen}
  \node[draw, red, line width=1pt, shape=rounded rectangle, inner sep=0,
        minimum width=0.2*\xLen, minimum height=0.2*\yLen]
     at (.5,.5) (rect) {};
  \node[red, font=\midfont] at (0.5-0.2, 0.5+0.2) (text) {Center is here};
  \draw[line width=1pt, red, ->] (text) -- (rect);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I highly appreciate your care dear frougon and the time you spent to write such a very instructive and excellent answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks again. Two questions: 1)What is the meaning of \the and \pgf@xx in \edef#1{\the\pgf@xx}
2) In which CTAN package we can find the explanation of \the and \pgf@xx in \edef#1{\the\pgf@xx}?

Comment: First, you need to read the [TikZ & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) on coordinate systems (p. 137 for version 3.1.9a). The `xyz` coordinate system allows one to define points using a linear combination of three base vectors called `x`, `y` and `z`. `\pgf@xx` is a ⟨dimen⟩ register (more precisely, a ⟨dimendef  token⟩) that says how much the `x` vector points to the right, `\pgf@xy` says how much the `x` vector points upwards, ... `\pgf@yy` says how much the `y` vector points upwards. ⟨dimen⟩ registers are TeX registers that contain rigid lengths.

Comment: `\the` followed by a ⟨dimendef  token⟩ expands to a string which is the length contained in the corresponding ⟨dimen⟩ register, in points. ⟨dimen⟩ registers, ⟨dimendef tokens⟩ and `\the` are explained in the TeXbook.

Answer (score 1):

1. `[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]` defines the *x-vector* and *y-vector* in the scoped coordinate system.
2. `inner sep` parameter (as `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`) is an absolute length. Its default unit is `pt`. So `inner xsep=30` is equivalent to `inner xsep=30pt`.

   To define a node with your requirements, you can use the `calc` and `fit` libraries.

   *Note: the rounded parts of the `rounded rectangle` shape can't contain text (look at the differences between the red and the orange nodes).*

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.misc,fit,calc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newcommand{\midfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{b}{n}\fontsize{15}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth] 
    {Mycena_interrupta.jpg}};
  \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    %\node at ( {.5+0},.5) [ red, line width=2 pt, shape=rounded rectangle,draw, inner xsep=30pt,inner ysep=20pt] (rect){};
    \node[fit={($(.5,.5)+(.2,.2)$)($(.5,.5)+(-.2,-.2)$)},shape=rounded rectangle,draw=red,inner sep=0,line width=2pt](rect){};
    \node at ( {.5-.3},{.5+.3}) (text){\textcolor{red}{\midfont{Center is Here}}};
    \draw [line width=3 pt, red][->] (text) -- (rect);
    \node[fit={($(.5,.5)+(.2,.2)$)($(.5,.5)+(-.2,-.2)$)},shape=rectangle,draw=orange,inner sep=0]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Paul for the good answer. Appreciate your care.