# Adjustment of the timeline connectors

Tags: timeline

I am using the `timeline` package by Arne Meier and I want to control the height of the timeline connectors, available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArneMeier/timeline). The option for customizing the color of the timeline connectors is available. Please consider the following code for typesetting the attached picture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{timeline}

\definecolor{Wyellow}{cmyk}{0.15,0.05,0.84,0}
\definecolor{WrandomI}{cmyk}{0.66,0.07,0.13,0.0}
\definecolor{WrandomII}{cmyk}{0.33,0.04,0.44,0.05}
\definecolor{WrandomIII}{cmyk}{0.55,0.15,0.54,0.0}
\definecolor{WrandomIV}{cmyk}{0.44,0.65,0.14,0.1}

\begin{document}

For changing the height of the timeline connectors by using the \verb|timeline| package.\\

\begin{timeline}[Wyellow][WrandomI][WrandomII][WrandomIII][WrandomIV] %where WrandomIV is the color of the timeline connectors.
 \timebar[3]{|}{0}{2000}{2013}{1}{|}
  \entry{2002}{entry}{no opacity}
  \entryshift{2003}{entryshift}{no opacity}{4mm}
  \flipentry{2004}{flipentry}{no opacity}
%  \flipentry{2005}{Anotherflipentry}{no opacity}
%   \flipentry{2005}{Anotherflipentry-I}{no opacity}
   \flipentry{2005}{NoOverlapIsExpected}{no opacity}
  \flipentryshift{2005}{flipentryshift}{no opacity}{4mm}
  \entry[0.5]{2008}{entry}{opacity}
  \entryshift[0.5]{2009}{entryshift}{opacity}{4mm}
  \flipentry[0.5]{2010}{flipentry}{opacity}
  \flipentryshift[0.2]{2011}{flipentryshift}{opacity}{4mm}
\end{timeline}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following outcome:

[image]

The expectation lies in getting the timeline whose picture is hand-written:

[image]

If it is possible to control the height of the timeline connectors, the overlapping can be avoided. The dots (in the hand-written picture as the connector lines) do not have to be the dots as the connector lines represent the same idea. The style file used for getting the timeline is the following:

```
%This package is under the MIT License. Copyright (c) 2018 Arne Meier.
%
%Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
%of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
%in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
%to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
%copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
%furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
%
%The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
%copies or substantial portions of the Software.
%
%THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
%IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
%FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
%AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
%LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
%OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
%SOFTWARE.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{timeline}[2018/04/03 timeline LaTeX package]

\RequirePackage{pgf}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc} % for length maxof

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.misc,calc}

\definecolor{uniblue}{rgb}{0.29,0.45,0.72}
\colorlet{timeline-what}{orange!75!white}
\colorlet{timeline-what-fg}{black}
\colorlet{timeline-who}{uniblue!75!white}
\colorlet{timeline-who-fg}{white}
\colorlet{timeline-connector}{orange!75!white}

\newcommand{\timelineInnerBG}[1]{\colorlet{timeline-what}{#1}}
\newcommand{\timelineInnerFG}[1]{\colorlet{timeline-what-fg}{#1}}
\newcommand{\timelineOuterBG}[1]{\colorlet{timeline-who}{#1}}
\newcommand{\timelineOuterFG}[1]{\colorlet{timeline-who-fg}{#1}}
\newcommand{\timelineConnector}[1]{\colorlet{timeline-connector}{#1}}
\newlength\timelineEntryMinHeight

%\setlength\timelineEntryMinHeight{.4cm}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\newlength\boxheightright
\newlength\boxheightleft



%%%% This part of the code (until the end marker) is licensed under cc by-sa 3.0, Paul Gaborit (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit)
%%%% It appeared as an answer to my question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424785/tikz-get-current-unit-length-of-x-coordinate) on TeX.StackExchange.
\def\getxlengthincm#1{
  \path let \p{x}=(1,0), \n{xlencm}={scalar(veclen(\x{x},\y{x})/1cm)}
  in \pgfextra{\xdef#1{\n{xlencm}}};
}
%%% End Marker


\NewDocumentEnvironment{timeline}{O {orange!75!white} O {black} O {uniblue!75!white} O {white} O {orange!75!white}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\timelineInnerBG{#1}%
\timelineInnerFG{#2}%
\timelineOuterBG{#3}%
\timelineOuterFG{#4}%
\IfNoValueTF{#5}{
    \timelineConnector{#1}%
}{
    \timelineConnector{#5}%
}
}{\end{tikzpicture}}

% \entrytemplate*type{year}{what}{where}{shift}
\NewDocumentCommand{\entrytemplate}{s m m m m o}{`
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yshiftval}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{-0.4cm}{0.3cm}\IfValueT{#6}{-#6}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xshiftval}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{-0.3cm}{0.2cm}\IfValueT{#6}{+#6}}
\setlength{\timelineEntryMinHeight}{\maxof{\heightof{#4}}{\heightof{#5}}+1.5mm}
    % label
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}

        % back ground white
        \node[anchor=\IfBooleanTF{#1}{east}{west},
          rotate=45,
          rounded rectangle,
          rounded rectangle \IfBooleanTF{#1}{west}{east} arc=none,
          font=\color{white}\footnotesize,
          fill=white,
          inner sep=.25mm,
          yshift=\yshiftval,
          xshift=\xshiftval,
          minimum height=\timelineEntryMinHeight,
          align=left] (#3-label) at (#3) {#4};
        \node[anchor=\IfBooleanTF{#1}{east}{west},
          rotate=45,
          rounded rectangle,
          rounded rectangle \IfBooleanTF{#1}{east}{west} arc=none,
          fill=white,
          inner sep=.25mm,
          font=\color{white}\footnotesize,
          minimum height=\timelineEntryMinHeight,
          align=left] at (#3-label.\IfBooleanTF{#1}{west}{east}) {#5};

        % first arg
        \node[anchor=\IfBooleanTF{#1}{east}{west},
          rotate=45,
          rounded rectangle,
          rounded rectangle \IfBooleanTF{#1}{west}{east} arc=none,
          font=\color{timeline-what-fg}\footnotesize,
          opacity = #2,
          fill=timeline-what,
          inner sep=.25mm,
          yshift=\yshiftval,
          xshift=\xshiftval,
          minimum height=\timelineEntryMinHeight,
          align=left] (#3-label) at (#3) {#4};
        % second arg
        \node[anchor=\IfBooleanTF{#1}{east}{west},
          rotate=45,
          rounded rectangle,
          rounded rectangle \IfBooleanTF{#1}{east}{west} arc=none,
          fill=timeline-who,
          opacity = #2,
          inner sep=.25mm,
          font=\color{timeline-who-fg}\footnotesize,
          minimum height=\timelineEntryMinHeight,
          align=left] at (#3-label.\IfBooleanTF{#1}{west}{east}) {#5};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % connector
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node[circle,inner sep=0mm,minimum width=1mm,fill=timeline-connector, opacity = #2] at (#3) {};
        \path let \p1 = (#3) in node (#3-goal) at (\x1,\IfBooleanTF{#1}{-1.15}{.85}) {};
        \draw[ultra thick,timeline-connector, opacity = #2] (#3.center) 
            \IfNoValueTF{#6}%
            { -- (#3.center|-#3-label.\IfBooleanTF{#1}{south east}{north west})}%
            { |- ([xshift=1mm]#3-label.\IfBooleanTF{#1}{north east}{west})};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\newcommand{\entry}[4][1]{
    \entrytemplate{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\newcommand{\flipentry}[4][1]{
    \entrytemplate*{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\newcommand{\entryshift}[5][1]{
    \entrytemplate{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}[#5]
}

\newcommand{\flipentryshift}[5][1]{
    \entrytemplate*{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}[#5]
}


% \timeline{intervalyear}{startsymbol}{startX}{fromyear}{toyear}{intervallength}{endsymbol}
\newcommand{\timebar}[7][5]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\timelineIntervalLength}{(#5-#4)+1} % length of interval with 1x at the end
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{|}}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\timelineOffset}{-.25}}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\timelineOffset}{0}}
    \draw[#2-#7] (#3+\timelineOffset,0) -- (#3+#6*\timelineIntervalLength,0);
    \foreach \l [count=\li] in {#4,...,#5}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\timelineX}{#3+(\li-1)*#6} % counter \li starts at 1, thus '-1' required. 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\timelineLengthY}{mod(\l,#1)==0?2:1} % if its divisible by 5 
        \draw (\timelineX,.\timelineLengthY) -- (\timelineX,-.\timelineLengthY) node[font=\footnotesize,yshift=-1.15mm]  {\ifthenelse{\timelineLengthY=2}{\l}{}};
        \node (\l) at (\timelineX,0) {};
    }

    \getxlengthincm{\myxlength}


    \pgfmathsetmacro{\timebarunit}{#6/12}
    \foreach \y in {#4,...,#5}{
        \foreach \m in {1,...,12}{
            \node[xshift=1cm*\myxlength*\timebarunit*(\m-1)] (\y-\m) at (\y) {};
        }
    }
}

% \timelinezigzag{start-x-coordinate}
\newcommand{\zigzag}[1]{
    \draw[-] (#1,0) -- (#1+0.1,-.4) -- (#1+0.2,.4) -- (#1+0.3,0) -- (#1+0.4,0);
}

\endinput
```

The aspect to label both of the sides (above and beneath) of the timeline is already considered; however, it is not present in the hand-written picture. About changing the angles of the labels, changes have to be made to the style file.

The primary reason for posting this question is to get recommendations about adjusting the height of the timeline connectors to avoid the overlapping labels (for example, by using this package, no two events can be created for the same year at the same position). The package also has a manual which can be compiled and the manual shows a command that seems to be the relevant one; however, using this command to control the height of the labels is still not completed:

```
\maxof{\heightof{#3}}{\heightof{#4}}+1.5mm
```

A few changes (as in using the spellings of the word 'connectors') were made in the `timeline`'s style file. Any suggestions to modify the `timeline.sty` file for getting the desired outcome will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome. // You could do e.g. by a) extending timeline.sty (rename it) or b) using several `\renewcommand` statements while keeping timeline.sty as is. Targets would be e.g. `\entry`, where you add a 5th optional parameter AND `\entrytemplate` which you copy and extend as needed. However, I think the best approach is contacting the author via GitHub about your request.