# What does the TIKZ option x = mean？

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm learning TIKZ drawing,
but I can't understand what the option x= in this code means,
can anyone explain it to me, thank you，
code show as below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[even odd rule,rounded corners=2pt,x=10pt,y=10pt]
\filldraw[fill=yellow!80!black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1)
[xshift=5pt,yshift=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (1,1)
[rotate=30] (-1,-1) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What does x=10pt mean here?

Comment: Reverse question of [context - Setting unit length in TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15994/setting-unit-length-in-tikz/15996#15996). Reading the answer there answers this question as well.

Comment: (there's also [nodes - Comprehensive list of TikZ style options? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95120/comprehensive-list-of-tikz-style-options) -- generally you can search for something like `/tikz/⟨option name⟩` in the manual but I'm not too sure about this one)

Comment: BTW, the default for TikZ is x=1cm and y=1cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 374 in the manual:

[image: About x-vector from the manual]

`x=10pt` sets the x-vector to be `10pt` instead of the normal `1cm` - so all coordinates are scaled.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @hebtuzrl, you shoulčd consider to accept answer ...